# Where are all the not-free Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, chrome-web-store

Chrome Web Store seems to allow for apps that [cost money](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/index#charging). However, I can't find any of them in the actual web store.

What does this mean?

Are paid apps just hugely unpopular and a bad way to go?

Does Chrome not allow for paid apps outside of the US (I live in Canada)?

Does anyone have any experience using a paid app in the web store?

Comment: Perhaps hard to disagree with three others, but I don't see the reasons for closing this question as off-topic. The OP is not asking for "application/website recommendations", but he's asking a question about the difference between "Chrome Web Store allows for paid extensions" and "Why are there so few (or not any) paid extensions?" and the reasons behind that. So, the suggestion "It is better instead to use a particular web app or website and ask for help in any issues you have with it specifically" is not a solution or alternative.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some of not-free Chrome extensions

- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/english-grammar/dmlipdpffkahdcimegmdfkkfnlmdgnjl?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/timed-test-division-facts/mimjmfnekgfaepenmgcfdekeenpocmcg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Answer (score 4):

I'm not finding any apps that have an initial charge either.  I am finding apps that require you to pay money in order to use them, but just not install them.  Netflix, for example.  You can install the app for nothing... the service is just useless without an account.  FreeMovies.com is another one.  The Chrome app costs nothing.  However, in order to actually watch movies through it, you need to pay a one time fee.  Plants vs. Zombies is a free trial, but if you want the game, you need to buy it.

Where are the apps you need to pay for?  I don't see anyone making them, and it's probably because they would have trouble getting people to purchase them.  Not the service... the Chrome App.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extension are written in javascript, and thus users are easily just copied your extension without huge effort. Thus you can say code are visible to users, thus there is no use to get paid your code. As mention Bon Gart, you can only get paid for online service.